# How to include javascript inside template tag(or component)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

#### What I'm trying to do

I need to use three(3) javascript libraries
[`plugin1.js` and `plugin2.js`] are plugins and depend on `base.js`

I'm trying to achieve this via `<script>` tag as shown below:
I'm doing this way because I was doing like this when I was using plain javascript.

```
<template>

  <div class="video">
    <script type="application/javascript" :src="`${publicPath}base.js`"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" :src="`${publicPath}plugin1.js`"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" :src="`${publicPath}plugin2.js`"></script>
    </script>
...
</template>
```

#### What is the problem

There are undefined errors like `Uncaught TypeError: blablabla_name is undefined`
Libraries not loaded into same scope.

#### Question

How can I load these libraries into same scope?

Comment: Import the scripts with the `import` keyword in your SFC's `<script>` (not in `<template>`). `publicPath` is likely static (e.g., stored in `assets/`), so just do `import '@/assets/base'`, `import '@/assets/plugin1'`, `import '@/assets/plugin2'`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by adding your external script into the vue mounted() of your component

```
<template>
   .... your HTML
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      ......data of your component
    }),
    mounted() {
      let recaptchaScript = document.createElement('script')
      recaptchaScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js')
      document.head.appendChild(recaptchaScript)
    },
    methods: {
      ......methods of your component
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This is vue, the question is how to do with Vue